# Entity Framework 6.4 + PostgreSQL Relationship One-to-One Unilateral don't include entity

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I have this code and relationships:

```
namespace Tequila.Models.DTOs
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [Column("id")]
        public long AddressId { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("user")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key, Column("id")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**User** -> id, name,...

**Address** -> id, address, user_id...

When I execute this route for find a user and your address, the SQL has generate is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, ... , u.password
  FROM user AS u
  WHERE u.id = @__Id_0
  LIMIT 1
```

I've already tried many other ideas by documents official and community, but I don't have success.

I'm not understanding what is happening with this problem.

## EDIT

I call the Include in context in my repository like this

```
User user = context.User.Include("Address").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
```

OR

```
User user = context.User.Include("Address").Where(u => u.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

And I create my *OnModelCreating* function

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("Address");
}
```

I tried many others configuration this function, but I still didn't succeed.

## EDIT 2

[image: This is the struture that I use to do]

I use this struture for to do this query of eager load. I tried to do another query with eager load too but with anothers entities and I had the same problem.

The address is not mandatory in user, but an user must is in address, in my case. So, I want to call an address when I call an user, and that user is on that address.

Comment: Can you please add code where you build your query? But i would say that you need to use [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Comment: Sorry, I added Include and the query that was generated was still the same

Comment: `HasForeignKey("Address")` this looks wrong. Can you add your actual database structure?

Comment: I added the structure and some comments. ps: I'm from Brazil, so my english is not good. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting only relationship (Foreign Key) via attributes not enough to get the related data on a query. For performance reason, as default behavior, EF doesn't return related objects as part of the query. You have to explicitly specify which related objects you want to return as part of your query.

Here below you can find sample code, so that while querying User object also gets Address details (the place where you created your query, you must have an instance of `ApplicationContext` class, I assume the name of the variable is **dbContext**):

`dbContext.User.Include(u => u.Address).ToList();`

The code above using **ToList()** method from Linq extension. If you use **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** package, you can also write an async version of the above code like below:

`dbContext.User.Include(u => u.Address).ToListAsync();`

**EDIT:**
With 2 new Edits on your questions, I am editing my answer as well.

Firstly, update your **OnModelCreating** method as below, basically, we remove **HasForeignKey** method (as you have already defined this relationship using attribute on your class) and also explicitly specify **WithOne** method to have one-to-one relationship with **User** property of **Address** entity (on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencenavigationbuilder.withone?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_ReferenceNavigationBuilder_WithOne_System_String_) 
 you can find how it behaves if you do not pass parameter, shortly it says *If the navigation property is to be used, then it must be specified.*):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOne(u => u.Address)
        .WithOne(a => a.User);
}
```

Secondly, your query part as below should work:

```
var user = context.User.Include(u => u.Address).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I have no idea what I'm doing the wrong

Comment: @Bruno Batista I updated the answer, please try and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thank's for your solution. When I removed the HasForeignKey method, the join works fine.